# How to better write multiple exceptions with redundant code in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, try-catch

How can I better write the following snippet in Python:

```
try:
    statement-1
except Exception1:
    codeblock-1
    codeblock-2
except Exception2:
    codeblock-2
```

Just to be clear, I want to execute two codeblocks when the first exception occurs, while only the latter of these two codeblocks when the second exception occurs.

Comment: Why not extract `codeblock-2` into a function, and call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options, as I see it; either:

1. Extract `codeblock-2` into a function and just call it (you repeat only one line this way); or
2. Catch both exceptions in the same `except`, then handle the two cases appropriately by checking the type of the caught exception.

Note that these aren't mutually exclusive, and the second approach is probably more readable if combined with the first. A snippet of the latter:

```
try:
    statement-1
except (Exception1, Exception2) as exc:
    if isinstance(exc, Exception1):
        codeblock-1
    codeblock-2
```

In action:

```
>>> def test(x, y):
    try:
        return x / y
    except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError) as exc:
        if isinstance(exc, TypeError):
            print "We got a type error"
        print "We got a type or zero division error"


>>> test(1, 2.)
0.5
>>> test(1, 'foo')
We got a type error
We got a type or zero division error
>>> test(1, 0)
We got a type or zero division error
```

Comment: What if the it weren't codeblocks and just oneliners? Thanks for the 2nd option though!

Comment: @Deepak if you only have one line for each case, then use option 2 and don't bother extracting the function.

Comment: I disagree, there is no difference between "block" and "oneliner". We use function not to save _lines_.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev as some point, you have to have the lines rather than another function call! Obviously, if writing the lines leads to duplication, you should extract a function. But if you have a single line to deal with that case, why would you extract it to a single-line function that's only called from one place?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, there are number of reasons. E. g. to give this action a _name_.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev that's one reason, and it may not apply. I have assumed that by *"just oneliners"* the OP means a trivial piece of code that requires no further explanation. I don't intend to override all of the general advice on when a function should be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

I would just straightforwardly use local function:

```
def exception_reaction():
    codeblock2()

try:
    statement1()
except Exception1:
    codeblock1()
    exception_reaction()
except Exception2:
    exception_reaction()
```