# Have exception hit two except blocks in python

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Here is an example of something I want to do in code:

```
class MyClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def test_func(cls, x):

        try:
            return cls.cache[x]

        except AttributeError:
            cls.cache = {}

        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            cls.cache[x] = "CACHE STORE"
            return cls.cache[x]
```

The idea here being my class will cache some results based on an input `x`.  However I don't want to start creating the cache until it's needed.  So the first time I pass any `x` into this, I want it to create the cache, and fill it with something.  Is there a way to make it hit both `except` blocks?  Right now it currently only hits the first

Comment: Sounds like you want a [singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)...

Comment: Creating an empty dict is going to add negligible overhead to the creation of your class. Just put `cache = {}` as a class attribute and be done with it.

Comment: I think you can adapt an answer I wrote earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30235268/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suggested in a comment, just make `cache` a class attribute when you create the class. Unless you have a *really* good reason not to, you're just needlessly complicating your implementation

```
class MyClass(object):

    cache = {}

    @classmethod
    def test_func(cls, x):
        try:
            return cls.cache[x]
        except KeyError:
            cls.cache[x] = "CACHE STORE"
            return cls.cache[x]
```

Once you do that, you don't even need `try` statement; you can just use `setdefault`.

```
@classmethod
def test_func(cls, x):
    return cls.cache.setdefault(x, "CACHE STORE")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for recursion here:

```
class MyClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def test_func(cls, x):

        try:
            return cls.cache[x]

        except AttributeError:
            cls.cache = {}
            return cls.test_func(x)  # Add this line

        except KeyError:
            cls.cache[x] = "CACHE STORE"
            return cls.cache[x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd

class MyClass(object):
    cache = dd(lambda: "CACHE STORE")
    @classmethod
    def test_func(cls, x):
        return cls.cache[x]
```

From the docs:

> Returns a new dictionary-like object. defaultdict is a subclass of the built-in dict class. It overrides one method and adds one writable instance variable. The remaining functionality is the same as for the dict class and is not documented here.
>
> The first argument provides the initial value for the default_factory attribute; it defaults to None. All remaining arguments are treated the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor, including keyword arguments.

I agree with the others that you lose nothing by just adding it as a class attribute from the beginning. But if you really insist on not creating the cache until it's needed, you can do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd

class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def test_func(cls, x):
        try:
            return cls.cache[x]
        except AttributeError:
            cls.cache = dd(lambda: "CACHE STORE")
            return cls.test_func(x)
```